# How to supply hostname using isc-dhcp-server to hosts without fixed-address

Tags: bind, internal-dns, isc-dhcp

I have a DHCP+DNS setup on my network using `bind9` and `isc-dhcp-server`. It works fine for all clients that have a "proper" hostname configured without any special setup in `dhcpd.conf` in the server. There are also a couple of hosts I have setup with fixed addresses using blocks like the following:

```
option domain-name "dyna.mynet";

host someserver {
  hardware ethernet 00:11:22:33:44:55;
  fixed-address someserver.mynet;   # someserver.mynet has a DNS entry in bind9
  server-name "nameserver.mynet";
}
```

So using the above, this host is reachable via `someserver.mynet` and via `someserver.dyna.mynet`.

However, without the `fixed-address` I can't get host sections like this working.

e.g. Another host block in the same `dhcpd.conf`

```
host worklaptop {
  hardware ethernet AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:00;
}
```

I've also tried:

```
host worklaptop {
  hardware ethernet AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:00;
  option host-name "worklaptop";
}
```

Neither works. I don't see any entries like `Added new forward map from ...` as I would expect in the logs.

Is there anything else I need to add?

> **Edit:**
>
> Just to clarify based on one of the comments, I don't need the actual device hostnames to change. I just need a DNS entry to be added, so I can address these devices using a DNS name.

**Related info:**

I think what the problem might be with the laptop is that it is a windows laptop and advertises the hostname with full work AD domain name e.g. `worklaptop.mywork.com`. And i don't have a DNS Zone for `mywork.com` in my LAN.

The other devices that don't get a name are things like Elgato lights, that have spaces in their hostname. I can't seem to override those hostnames either with these `host` blocks in the `dhcpd.conf` file.

Comment: You can not set a windows hostname over DHCP, it simply don't accept it. But if it is only the DNS that DHCP updates then you should be able to modify that.

Comment: Yes, I don't need the actual device hostname (including the windows laptop hostname) to change. I just need a dns forward entry in the zone managed by bind. I don't get these added for the above hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names for DNS entries should be specified by the `ddns-hostname` option for every client you want to create DNS record for. According to the [dhcpd.conf man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcpd.conf):

> ddns-hostname name;
>
> The name parameter should be the hostname that will be used in setting up the client's A and PTR records. If no ddns-hostname is specified in scope, then the server will derive the hostname automatically, using an algorithm that varies for each of the different update methods.

Note that the `ddns-hostname` should contain the host name only, the domain name will be appended using the value given in the `domain-name` option.

Comment: Thanks. With this change I can override devices with malformed hostnames. For the windows domain controlled laptop though, I also had to add `ignore client-updates;`